# How can I send Windows Media Center remote WM_INPUT messages from a C# application?

Tags: c#

I am writing an application to control Windows 7, especially Windows Media Center. I can send key strokes, execute commands etc. but I would like to emulate some of the buttons on the Media Center Remote.

Some of these are WM_INPUT messages, as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb417079.aspx

I would like to send these messages in such a way as they can be received by any application that traps MCE remote messages, so that the app can be used more widely, so would prefer not to have to send messages to a specific window.

I know that some of these commands can replicated using keyboard shortcuts, but these won't be valid in other applications.

Does anyone know how I can send these messages from C# application?

Here is what I have put together so far:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

const int WM_INPUT = 0x00FF;
const int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;
const int COMMAND = 0;

PostMessage((IntPtr)HWND_BROADCAST, WM_INPUT, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)COMMAND);
```

But I don't know how to construct the message itself, or even whether this approach will work at all.

If I am barking up the wrong tree, then do please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but looking at the link you posted + this page in MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418864(v=vs.85).aspx#WM_INPUT

It seems that you need to declare the structure [RAWINPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645562%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in your C# app, fill it out with the data that corresponds to the command that you want to send, and pass a pointer to it in lParam.